# Loadins Starling swf within another swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I have an swf which does not use stage3D it's a simple swf. I also have an swf which runs starling. Now, I want to load the starling swf inside the first swf. Is something like that possible?

Comment: @Rizzla why is there performace issues ?  Stage3d runs on a different layer than normal stage so I see no issues.

Comment: @Adrian Pirvulescu In the book for Starling form O'Reilly said so. But, it was a while when I first read it about, now it says it wont impact the performance after they update it...

Comment: Yes it is possible - http://www.roguish.com/blog/?p=495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes it is possible.

Hints:

- you have to set the backgroundAlpha = 0, in your normal flash file, in order to be able to see the stage3D context.
- take care your html file which is the wraper for flash, specifies that wmode = direct
- watch out how you unload / stop the starling content when you do not need it any more.

Performance:

- As long as you release the resources that you do not need, having a mix should not cause performance issues.
- Try not to perform heavy operations on both normal flash and starling content in the same time.

Comment: It seems to work. What I do is load the starling just like any other swf and talk to starling normally and adjust the frame rate. The only thing to watch out is when starling starts it starts throwing addedToStage event if there is a listener in the main parent class. That gets messy. Get around it and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you just need to remember that stage3d content (starling) will always be below display list. Performance should only be issue on mobile, if you only target web it should be fine.